# Can I configure xdebug in Sublime Text 2 to give more information on objects/ arrays?

Tags: php, sublimetext2, xdebug

When I am using xdebug, I can see the values of each variable at certain breakpoints. But, sometimes I'd like to view more that a cropped version of an object/ or array:

```
$userSession = Zend_Session_Namespace[1]
    CLASSNAME = (string) Zend_Session_Namespace
    $userSession->_namespace = (string) QA_Session
    ...
```

Is there a way to configure xdebug in ST to do this\? I'm having a look at http://xdebug.org/docs/display, it seems to give some instruction on setting child depth etc, but I don't see in xdebug config json file in ST. Ideally I'd like just something like var_dump would output, but in full (children, all elements). Thanks